# HTML5 ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, gstreamer

I'm using gstreamer to send video to HTML5 webpage.
The following code works in Firefox, but not working in Chrome with error below:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

**Sender**

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=360,framerate=30/1 ! \
videoconvert ! theoraenc ! oggmux ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=5003
```

**Receiver**

```
<video autoplay="" width="640" height="360">
    <source src="http://127.0.0.1:5003" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Is chrome waiting for HTTP 200 OK response?  If yes, which software component should reply it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this trying to connect to my local livereload port with:

on my page at:
http://192.168.1.72:35729/

GET http://192.168.1.72:35729/livereload.js?ver=1.0 net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Works in Firefox also for me. on mac os.